# Ruby Singleton avoid using instance member

Tags: ruby

I like Ruby's singleton but I would like to make usage of it better so here is example

```
require 'singleton'

class Foo
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    # code to setup singleton here 
  end

  def self.get_bar
    Foo.instance.get_bar
  end

  def get_bar
  end

  def get_nar
  end
end
```

Usage

`Foo.instance.get_bar` (default) or `Foo.get_bar` (due to static `self.get_bar` method I made)

Is there elegant way to make all methods accessible without me having to write static wrapper for each method? Just seems redundant to have to write for each method `.instance`

**UPDATE**

Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Do you actually need to use the Singleton module? Foo is already a singleton and you can just do Foo.get_bar.

Comment: This is just example. I have Configuration singleton which hold configuration from many files in hash map. So I need singleton which will read those files only once and persist hash map...

Comment: You can also do that without the Singleton module.

Comment: Yes, but prefer it this way since its much cleaner implementation.

Comment: How? Updated question to show it is not RoR project.

Comment: @Dolphin you're not making this easy. Why is it tagged ruby-on-rails?

Comment: @Beerlington No need to down vote it, I mark it as ROR so more people see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mix this module:

```
module DelegateToSingleton

  def respond_to_missing?(method)
    super || instance.respond_to?(method)
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    instance.send(method, *args)
  end

end
```

into your singleton:

```
class Foo

  extend DelegateToSingleton
  include Singleton

  def foo
    'foo'
  end

  def bar
    'bar'
  end

end
```

with these results:

```
p Foo.foo    # => "foo"
p Foo.bar    # => "bar"
```

`DelegateToSingleton::method_missing` is what makes it work: Whenever Foo receives a method it doesn't know about, it just forwards it to its instance.

`DelegateToSingleton::respond_to_missing?` is not strictly needed, but having it is good manners whenever playing tricks with method_missing.

For Ruby earlier than 1.9.2: [Override `respond_to?` instead of `respond_to_missing?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20731357/238886)

Answer (score 3):

Just separate the class from the instance:

```
class Foo
  def initialize 
  end

  def get_bar
  end

  def get_nar
  end
end

MyFoo = Foo.new
MyFoo.get_bar
```

Comment: Than it is not singleton it is just instance.

Comment: Pedantry. It gives you the interface and behaviour you're going for in a much better way (better meaning more testable, more flexible, more obvious).

Comment: Like said before this example was just to simplify my problem. Real problem needs to be solved with singleton, since creation of instance is expensive. Passing reference of this instance would be just creating spaghetti code.

Comment: There is only one instance (the instance stored at `MyFoo`) and you incur more overhead delegating to it than you do just directly referencing it, as this does. Furthermore, this is a singleton in that it gives you a global point of access to a single instance. It only differs in that it doesn't restrict you from creating new ones. I think you're confusing the GoF's implementation with its definition. And frankly, I think the mentioned difference only exists because they defined it from the POV of Java where you can't do things like the above (which also explains their implementation)

Comment: Got it now, dynamic assignment is not possible with 1.8.7 now I see what you did, works with 1.9.

Well to be honest this is not bad, not bad at all, I agree with you this is good solution. Thank you for enlightenment. Vote up, accept goes to Wayne since it meets 1.8.7 criteria.

Comment: @Dolphin, The dynamic assignment is a symptom of a problem with your program: Some files, when required, are being loaded more than once.  The reason 1.9 fixes that is because it normalizes the path before checking to see if a file has already been required; 1.8.7 does not.  Change your requires so that they all use the same literal as the path, or to use File.expand_path to normalize the paths, and you won't get the dynamic assignment anymore.  Once you've fixed the problem with required files being loaded more than once, which you ought to anyway, then this is the better solution.