# How are respond_to and respond_to_missing different?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm confused when to use each of this methods. 
From `respond_to?` documentation:

> Returns true if *obj* responds to the given method. Private methods
>   are included in the search only if the optional second parameter
>   evaluates to true.
>
> If the method is not implemented, as Process.fork on Windows,
>   File.lchmod on GNU/Linux, etc., false is returned.
>
> If the method is not defined, respond_to_missing? method is called and
>   the result is returned.

And `respond_to_missing?`:

> Hook method to return whether the *obj* can respond to *id* method or
>   not.
>
> See #respond_to?.

Both methods takes 2 arguments.
Both methods seems to the same thing(check if some object respond to given method) so why we should use(have) both?

Defining 'resond_to_missing?` gives you ability to take methods:

```
class A
  def method_missing name, *args, &block
    if name == :meth1
      puts 'YES!'
    else
      raise NoMethodError
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing? name, flag = true
    if name == :meth1
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

[65] pry(main)> A.new.method :meth1
# => #<Method: A#meth1>
```

Why `respond_to?` couldn't do this?

#### What I guess:

`respond_to?` checks if method is in:

1. Current object.
2. Parent object.
3. Included modules.

`respond_to_missing?` checks if method is:

1. Defined via `method_missing`:

Via array of possible methods:

```
def method_missing name, *args, &block
  arr = [:a, :b, :c]
  if arr.include? name
    puts name
  else
    raise NoMethodError
  end
end
```

Delegating it to different object:

```
class A
  def initialize name
    @str = String name
  end

  def method_missing name, *args, &block
    @str.send name, *args, &block
  end
end
```

2 . Other way that I'm not aware of.

#### Where should both be defined/used(my guessing too):

Starting from 1.9.3(as fair I remember) define only `respond_to_missing?` but use only `respond_to?`

#### *Last questions*:

Am I right? Did I missed something? Correct everything that is bad and/or answer questions asked in this *question*.

Comment: [This thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4416474#1119074) may be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

`respond_to_missing?` is supposed to be updated when you make available additional methods using the method missing technique. This will cause the Ruby interpreter to better understand the existence of the new method.

In fact, without using `respond_to_missing?`, you can't get the method using [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-method).

[Marc-André posted a great article](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/methodmissing-politely.html) about the `respond_to_missing?`.

> In order for respond_to? to return true, one can specialize it, as follows:
>
> ```
> class StereoPlayer
>   # def method_missing ...
>   #   ...
>   # end
>
>   def respond_to?(method, *)
>     method.to_s =~ /play_(\w+)/ || super
>   end
> end
> p.respond_to? :play_some_Beethoven # => true
> ```
>
> This is better, but it still doesn’t make play_some_Beethoven behave exactly like a method. Indeed:
>
> ```
> p.method :play_some_Beethoven
> # => NameError: undefined method `play_some_Beethoven'
> #               for class `StereoPlayer'
> ```
>
> Ruby 1.9.2 introduces `respond_to_missing?` that provides for a clean solution to the problem. Instead of specializing `respond_to?` one specializes `respond_to_missing?`. Here’s a full example:
>
> ```
> class StereoPlayer
>   # def method_missing ...
>   #   ...
>   # end
>
>   def respond_to_missing?(method, *)
>     method =~ /play_(\w+)/ || super
>   end
> end
>
> p = StereoPlayer.new
> p.play_some_Beethoven # => "Here's some_Beethoven"
> p.respond_to? :play_some_Beethoven # => true
> m = p.method(:play_some_Beethoven) # => #<Method: StereoPlayer#play_some_Beethoven>
> # m acts like any other method:
> m.call # => "Here's some_Beethoven"
> m == p.method(:play_some_Beethoven) # => true
> m.name # => :play_some_Beethoven
> StereoPlayer.send :define_method, :ludwig, m
> p.ludwig # => "Here's some_Beethoven"
> ```

See also [Always Define respond_to_missing? When Overriding method_missing](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding/).