# How do you make all attributes public in ruby class

Tags: ruby, class, attributes

I have a class with 20+ attributes, I want each of them to be publicly readable or if not that then public.

I cannot seem to find any data relevant to this. Can anyone help me here please?

**I want to make all of them public without having to type all 20+ attributes with attr_reader.**

Comment: do you know `attr_reader` method in Ruby ? Use it like `attr_reader :x, :y, ..`

Comment: There are 20+ attributes, how do I make them all public, without typing all of them?

Comment: So, you want Ruby to read your mind? I don't get it. How is Ruby supposed to know what the names of those attributes are if you don't tell it?

Comment: Would you write all those attributes yourself? Or prefer a clever way to automate this task. I'd go with automating this task. One answer posted below did the job but the author has removed it so I mark it any more. It had a clever approach, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `method_missing`.  `method_missing` is called whenever someone tries to call a method that your class doesn't know how to respond to.

```
class Foo

  def initialize
    @a = 1
    @b = 2
    @c = 3
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(name)
    super || has_attribute?(name)
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    if has_attribute?(name)
      instance_variable_get("@#{name}")
    else   
      super
    end
  end

  private

  def has_attribute?(name)
    instance_variable_defined?("@#{name}")
  end

end
```

Here's what it looks like when you use it

```
foo = Foo.new
p foo.a    # => 1
p foo.b    # => 2
p foo.c    # => 3
p foo.d    # => method_missing error
```

*Note*: For Ruby earlier than 1.9.2: [Override `respond_to?` instead of `respond_to_missing?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20731357/238886)